# Copy Remote MS SQL AWS RDS Database to Local Development Machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Can anybody tell me how to copy my AWS RDS database to my local development machine? 
Is there anyway to do this? I am using MS SQL and the remote RDS Instance was created 
alongside an Elastic Beanstalk EC2 Instance.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have access to the management studio? You should be able to use the import / export features of the management studio to grab a copy of the RDS database and import it locally. There's also the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio, it might have some tools for RDS backup or export.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this.  AWS remove access to the underlying file system - therefore you can't actually copy the database.  Amazon also do not provide any export / import functionality.

The best advice I can offer is to use SQL Server Management Studio or equivalent (ie - RedGate SQL Compare) to do this.

RedGate offer a trial product - and this is what I've used when I've had to do this in the past.